# How To Extend A File Size In OpenFileDialog C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am making an expand-file-size program in C#, but I am having a problem.  Everything works fine, but I don't have code to actually expand the size of the file that I select from `OpenFileDialog`.  Does anyone know how to expand a file's size in C#?  I need to extend each file +16.  I am familiar with EOF (end-of-file), but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Expand it with what?  Spaces as text?  Null bytes?

Comment: Do not capitalize each word! It Just Looks Ugly.

Comment: EOF(End Of File) @StevenDoggart

Comment: You aren't making sense.  I assume when you said that you want to "expand the file size +16" that you meant that you wanted to add 16 bytes to the end of the file.  But It's not clear if they are text files or some other format.  If they are text files, what encoding are they?  In any case, of what do you want those 16 bytes to be comprised?  Null bytes?  Spaces?

Comment: @StevenDoggart I meant expand my 8 mbps file to be added 16 mega bytes and my file is not a text file.Its a blank file.It has 8 mbps file size and all i want to do is make it 24 mbps means add more 16 mega bytes.

Comment: By *mbps*, I assume you mean MB (megabytes)?  (mbps is a measure of communication speed (megabits per second), not size)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to append to a file. Look at the file open function documentation - you can open a file for appending.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to do something like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;

        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(dialog.FileName);
        using (var stream = new FileStream(dialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            stream.SetLength(fileInfo.Length + 16);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to create a copy of that file with 16 added length with other extension.I used this code to copymy file::File.Copy(textBox1.Text, (oldFile + type)); and i want my copied file to be expanded not the natural one.Extending the original file by coping the real file to natural will also do.I mean my file is 8 mb and it will be copied and be expanded to 16 mb by changing extension.

Comment: When I use the code it crashes and says "Cannot access "My File Destination" Because Its Being Used By Another Process."

Comment: @SudhirSundar I didn't encounter any problems when I tested it. I hope you can get it working.

Comment: Can you convert it to C++.